# WebFlux - how to use Flux<GroupTreeItem> as List<GroupTreeItem> parameter in service method

Tags: stream, spring-webflux

I use Spring Boot and Webflux. I wonder how to use my allUserGroups :

```
             public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<GroupTreeItem>>> userAllTreeGroups(
 //1
                 Flux<UUID> groupIds = userGroupService
    .findUserGroupByEmail(email)
    .flatMap(groupById -> userGroupService.findUserTreeGroup(groupById.getId(), email))
    .map(GroupTreeItem::getId);

    //2
             rolePrivilegesService
                    .filterGroupIdsForUserPrivilege(Arrays.asList(allUserGroups?????????), "group.permission.all")
                    .flatMap(filteredGroupId -> userGroupService.findUserTreeGroup(filteredGroupId, email))
                    .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                    .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
        }
```

where:

```
 public Mono<List<UUID>> filterGroupIdsForUserPrivilege(List<UUID> groupIds, String privilege)
```

and

```
public class GroupTreeItem   {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private UUID id;
...
...}
```

RECAP:
my problem is how to pass

```
Flux<UUID> groupIds
```

to:

```
rolePrivilegesService
                    .filterGroupIdsForUserPrivilege(myListOfUUID, "group.permission.all")
```

And here the body of

> userGroupService.findUserTreeGroup:

```
 public Mono<GroupTreeItem> findUserTreeGroup(UUID groupId, String email) {
    return groupByIdRepo.findById(groupId).flatMap(group -> findAndPopulateChildData(email, group));
      }
```

How to achieve that in Webflux without breaking a chain as non-blocking operation?

Comment: use `Flux::collectToList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned *K.Nicholas* in the comment you need to transform Flux to Mono> by `Flux::collectToList` operation and propogate your list in the chain like this:

```
userGroupService
    .findUserGroupByEmail(email)
    .flatMap(groupById -> userGroupService.findUserTreeGroup(groupById.getId(), email))
    .map(GroupTreeItem::getId)
    .collectToList()
    .flatMap(myListOfUUID -> rolePrivilegesService.filterGroupIdsForUserPrivilege(myListOfUUID, "group.permission.all"))
    .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)  
    .flatMap(filteredGroupId -> userGroupService.findUserTreeGroup(filteredGroupId, email))
    .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
    .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

if you need transform Mono> to Flux use `.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)` but better way change method `rolePrivilegesService.filterGroupIdsForUserPrivilege` to return `Flux`

Comment: Everything almost OK but in the line flatMap(filteredGroupId -> userGroupService.findUserTreeGroup(filteredGroupId, email)) I need to pass one GroupTreeItem instead of List<GroupTreeItem> that currently is in filteredGroupId : .flatMap(filteredGroupId ->... I added implementation of userGroupService.findUserTreeGroup in my post

Comment: Could you change filterGroupIdsForUserPrivilege to return Flux<UUID> instead of Mono<List<UUID>>?

Comment: Yauhen Balykin - your solution WORKS:) I totally forgot about flatMapMany

Comment: Great, nice to hear)